# How to call PUT method with URI parameters (not direct query string)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-put

I have an api method,

```
    [Route("v1/user-details/{userId}/complete")]
    [HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage CompleteUser(string userId) 
    {
        // code here           
    }
```

How do i consume the same from windows application with code behind C#

already tried with the below which is not working,

```
   public void CompleteUserDetails(string userId)
   {

    Uri putUrl = new Uri(userURL + "/" + userId + "/complete");
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
       client.Headers.Clear();
       client.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

       var formData = new NameValueCollection{
                    {"", ""}
                };

       var d = client.UploadValues(putUrl, "PUT", formData);
       if (d != null)
       {

       }
     }
    }
```

Getting bad request error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Cletas, welcome to StackOverflow.  Can you edit your post and include the full exception you're receiving?

Comment: try changing `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` to `"application/json"` because i noticed you're sending `formData` OR, you know what, what would happen if you didn't pass in `formData`?

Comment: It worked when I removed the formData variable and sent string.empty.  Thank you guys for the support.